# ruby regex lookbehind with optional substring

Tags: regex

Matching an optional substring in a lookbehind is apparently invalid lookbehind syntax...

I am trying to match the word `static`, but only when preceded by `url(` (either with or without the optional single quote)

```
(?<=url\([']?)static
```

should match both:

url('**static** with quotes')

url(**static** without quotes)

i resorted to doing 2 lookbehinds, but it seems unnecessary

```
(?:(?<=url\()|(?<=url\('))static
```

Is there a regex trick i can leverage here?

Here is a link to it in rubular: http://rubular.com/r/iJ3ifrOmfZ

Comment: Very few regex engines allow for variable length lookbehinds. You might just try a *capture group*: `url\('?(static)`.

Answer (score 0):

@tenub is right, and not many regex engines allow variable length lookbehinds.  `'?` makes the look behind variable length, because it may or may not have that extra character.  Your solution works, but this may also be a situation where you can [leverage `\K`](http://regex101.com/r/yC4qK4) (which restarts your match).

```
url\(    # matches url( literally
'?       # matches an optional '
\K       # reset your match (similar to if you had used a lookbehind)
static   # match static literally
```

I've also made an [expanded syntax](http://regex101.com/r/fN0yT4) that will match an entire string within `url()` or `url('')` as long as it starts with your `static` keyword.  This one works as expected, since you can have variable length lookaheads.

```
url\('?\Kstatic.*?(?='?\))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a trick? Yes.

**First trick:** \K (already mentioned by Sam), i.e. `url\('?\Kstatic`

**Second trick:**

```
(?<=url\(|url\(')static
```

This is because ruby will allow a variable lookbehind of pre-determined length.

**Third trick:**

```
(?<=(?<=url\()'|(?<=url\())static
```

A variation on the second trick

**Fourth trick:**

```
url\('?(static)
```

"static" will be captured in Group 1.

The apostrophe is optional, so both strings will match.

Demos for trick # 4 (look at Group 1): http://regex101.com/r/eV5fN4 and http://regex101.com/r/qT0tG8

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable length lookbehind in Ruby using an alternation. But, the alternation must be at the ground level of the lookbehind subpattern:

Working patterns:

```
(?<=url\('|url\()static
(?<=(?:url\('|url\())static # the non-capturing group is ignored because useless
```

don't work

```
(?<=url\((?:'|))static      # the alternation is not at the ground level
(?<(?:url\('|url\()s)tatic  # doesn't work too.
```